# Trigger Email on specific date #2

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have made application...that can have numbers of Event on Specified Date, So i want to code tat when time for event is arrived so tat automatically the participant get information about the event..so i want to send email to all participant before a day.

Comment: Windows has the Task Scheduler to do this.

Comment: Please just use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the scheduling in code of your app, a great library is Quartz.NET. Check it out here:

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

You can create jobs with various triggers and the job code can be used to handle the email.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about writing services and such, just use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and set it to run your app daily at the desired time. It's absolutely perfect for this sort of job.